# Integrate $\frac{ e^{i k | \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} |} }{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} |}$ in a spherical shell

Tags: integration, volume, greens-function, electromagnetism

How can we compute the following triple integral (electromagnetic diffusion in a sphericall shell)?

$ E(\mathbf{r}) = \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi' \int_0^{\pi} \sin \theta' d\theta' \int_R^{R+h} d r' r'^2 \frac{ e^{i k | \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} |} }{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'} |} $

Using $\mathbf{r} . \mathbf{r'} = r r' \left( \sin \theta \sin \theta' \cos(\phi - \phi') + \cos \theta \cos \theta' \right) $, I tried to integrate first by $r'$ or $\theta'$ but I did not found primitives with online integrator.
I think the answer is simple but I can't find it (I have the result for an integration over a cylinder only but not for the spherical shell).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You are free to choose the system of coordinate $X'Y'Z'$ in the space. You can direct the $Z'$-axix along $\vec r$. In this case $|\vec r-\vec r'|=\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos \theta}$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle. Next, $\sin\theta d\theta=d(\cos\theta)$, and the integration is indeed straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot Svyatoslav, I did not know we can do that. So with this help, I found:

$E = \frac{2 i \pi}{k^3 r} e^{i k r} \left\lbrace \left[ 1-i k (R+h) \right] e^{- i k (R+h)} - \left[ 1-i k R \right] e^{- i k R} + \left[ 1-i k R \right] e^{i k R} - \left[ 1-i k (R+h) \right] e^{ i k (R+h)}     \right\rbrace $